# Add a proxy header using python requests

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests

Specs: Python 2.7.9, Requests 2.12.4, Windows OS

```
s = requests.Session()
proxy = {'http':'http://ip:port',
         'https':'http://ip:port'}
r_url = "https://api.ipify.org"
s.get(r_url,verify=False,timeout=5,proxies=proxy,headers=headers)
```

Problem:
I need to add a "HOST" header to HTTP CONNECT method. It doesn't seem like requests or urllib3 is sending this header or is in a format not excepted by the proxy server;"Host":"api.ipify.org". Adding a host header is the solution but I'm not sure whats the best way to go about it.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I could solve it with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382010/4041230